# Exporting all tables into files from SQL Server database using utility bulk copy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I want to bcp all tables into files from a database:

```
SELECT 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp '           --bcp
+  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'               --database name
+  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+ '.'  -- schema
+  QUOTENAME(name)                         -- table
+ ' out c:\temp\'                          -- output directory
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_'
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                    -- file name
+ '.txt -T -c'''   -- extension, security
FROM sys.tables
```

it produces statements like this:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp [AdventureWorks2012].[Production].[ScrapReason] out c:\temp\Production_ScrapReason.txt -T -c'

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Shift] out c:\temp\HumanResources_Shift.txt -T -c'
```

so what I want is to iterate over above statements and execute all them. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Note this assumes all commands are unique.

```
DECLARE @Commands TABLE(CommandText NVARCHAR(4000));
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);

INSERT INTO @Commands
SELECT 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp '           --bcp
+  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'               --database name
+  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+ '.'  -- schema
+  QUOTENAME(name)                         -- table
+ ' out c:\temp\'                          -- output directory
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_'
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                    -- file name
+ '.txt -T -c'''   -- extension, security
FROM sys.tables

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Commands) > 0
BEGIN --Command Processing
    SET @SQL = (SELECT TOP 1 CommandText FROM @Commands)
    --PRINT (@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)
    DELETE FROM @Commands WHERE CommandText = @SQL
END
```

Comment: I have not tried yet because I had not time but the backup (c:\temp\...) done where is IT placed? in my local machine or in the remote machine?

Comment: On the server you run the script on. To get it elsewhere us a unc path.

Comment: Watch out for `Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell'` which has to be enabled to be able run the above sql. I avoided this by altering the sql to print the bare bcp commands and creating a .bat file from that.

Answer (score 0):

Default setting is that you can't execute bcp command from SQL server. This version works from DOS, Powershell and BAT file.

I didn't find setting from BCP which would export the heading line on these CSV files, so note that these CSV files don't include heading.

```
-- Run this command to the database you wish to export
DECLARE @Commands TABLE(CommandText NVARCHAR(4000));
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);

INSERT INTO @Commands
SELECT 'bcp '           --bcp
+  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'               --database name
+  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+ '.'  -- schema
+  QUOTENAME(name)                         -- table
+ ' out c:\temp\csvdump\'                  -- output directory
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_'
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                    -- file name
+ '.csv -T -C 65001 -t "|" -k -c -S localhost'   -- extension, security
FROM sys.tables

-- Copy-paste results to DOS or Powershell prompt or create a BAT file from these.
SELECT 'mkdir c:\temp\csvdump'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM @Commands
```