# Backup entire sql server database using bcp

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Is it possible to backup entire sql server database into one unique file using bcp?

Comment: Sure, as long as your database has only one table. In practical terms, the answer is no.

Comment: @acfrancis My database has multiple tables. so the answer is 'no' as i understand.

Comment: Correct. Why would you want to do that anyway? A proper backup is much better in most cases.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19934411/10245

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server BCP does not support this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx